# Is there a way to push a new view in a popoverview controller without making it disappear?

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, visible, popover

I have a popover view in a splitview and when the user selects an option in the popover menu, I want to push a new list into the popover view.  I want the menu to remain visible but it disappears as soon as the user selects an item.  Is there a way to keep it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only need to find this line in your project

```
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

the line written above disapepearing your popover so just comment this line in yr project for that particular popover u declared that u dnt want to let it disappear.